# Topic Challenge Ideas Meta Post

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post serves as a master meta post for topic challenge ideas. Please post your answers suggesting topics we can use as topic challenge ideas.

Also bear in mind that

- there should only be one idea per answer so votes would mean something.
- only upvotes will be counted. You're free to downvote answers you don't like, and if we were to choose between two answers with the same score, the one with fewer downvotes will be chosen.
- the votes will be tallied every two weeks.
- suggested topics must be tags with at least 25 questions, or popularly discussed topics (think of a keyword that appears some 100 times in posts here)

Comment: [tag:iupac] would be my favourite

Comment: @Martin - マーチン Sadly it was deleted.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest [organometallic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organometallic-compounds).

Right now it may seem that we have a fair amount of questions (111), but a large number of them are organic chemistry based: e.g. what happens if I treat XYZ substrate with a Grignard reagent, Pd coupling, etc. and the focus is on the organic substrate, not the metal. The tag then gets added not because it's a question on organometallic chemistry per se, but rather because it's an organic chemistry reaction in which some metal was used.

I'd like to see more questions about the more "inorganic" side of the subject (there is tons of scope for this: main group, d-block and even f-block organometallic chemistry is well-developed. Elschenbroich's text is an excellent and comprehensive overview.). Or at the very least, some stuff about the role of the metal/ligands in the organic reactions, like [this recent question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80627/oxidative-addition-electronics-of-the-catalyst/80707#80707) on OA in Pd couplings.

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest [supramolecular-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supramolecular-chemistry).

---

Supramolecular chemistry won the 2016 Nobel prize and is a *vast* field (self assembly, molecular machinery, dynamic covalent chemistry, template synthesis), yet very few questions here on chem.SE about the topic. Would be nice to expand this!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest [computational-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry).

---

It's a rapidly growing area of chemistry, is broad enough to bring in a large number of questions, and is darn cool.

Comment: I guess a huge benefit of this is that we do have the user base to answer such questions. I've been trying to post stuff, but (perhaps understandably) not getting all that many answers.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [solid-state-chemistry](/questions/tagged/solid-state-chemistry)

---

While this tag has seen a decent amount of use, I think it could lead to some interesting questions or good canonical answers. The field has a lot of neat ideas that could be covered (photovoltaics, metal organic frameworks, crystal structures). I could also see some tie-ins with [computational-chemistry](/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry) in terms of solid state modeling and electronic structure programs.

Answer (score 2):

And I would like to add [analytical-chemistry](/questions/tagged/analytical-chemistry)

---

A few relevant sub-domains:

Chemical measurements, chemical statistics, experimentation, sampling, sample pretreatment, measurement, signal processing and validation, calibration, evaluation, data interpretation (p-values, chi-sq), latent variables, chemometrics, chemical information, intra- and inter-lab robustness and validation, error...

forensics, -omics, spectroscopy, (mass) spectrometry, chromatography, electrophoresis, standard addition, regression, components and factor analyses. Thanks!