# Ask questions about [drugs] and [medicinal-chemistry]! (Topic challenge)

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

Seeing that we aren't receiving a lot of questions with [drugs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drugs) and [medicinal-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicinal-chemistry) and answers as well, I am hereby requesting interested users to participate in these tags, to improve diversity of this community.

This is similar to other topic challenges of the past: [Topic Challenge Ideas Meta Post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/topic-challenge-ideas-meta-post)

Ideally its a way of trying to encouraging experts in the medicinal chemistry fields, pharmacologists etc to bring and share their knowledge with the community.

---

<sup>Just a brief background about me: I am an intern in the medical field (pharmacy) specialising in Oncology. I have a fair understanding of medicinal chemistry and very good understanding of pharmacology and just wish to learn more from other users and sharing my knowledge as well to keep this community highly diversied</sup>